# Birt Reports - Adding percentages to chart legend

Tags: charts, birt

Is it possible to add percentages to the chart legend, or is it the only way to put percentages to the chart, by adding the "Percentile Value Data"?[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the percentile value is usually something different, it only makes sense if the categories are based on intervals, e.g. given 7 billion living humans and measuring their age, the top 0.1 percentile are the 7_000_000_000 * 0.1/100 = 7_000_000 oldest living humans.

So, percentile values make sense for things you can measure, like age, income, length - in other words, numbers, or at least things which can be ordered.
You wouldn't use a pie chart then.

Percentile values don't make sense for things that cannot be measured like car labels.

Take a look at https://forums.opentext.com/forums/developer/discussion/48914/how-to-create-pie-chart-with-percentage-instead-of-values

M Williams writes there (I just repeat this here):

In the chart editor, you can go to the "format data" tab, then to the value series section, click on the "labels" button at the bottom, delete the "value data" option from the values window, then from the dropdown below the window, choose the percentage option and add it. This will show your pie chart labels in percentage.